# Concatinating two different size of lists in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have two lists of matrices, `LIST1` (size m), and `LIST2`(size n). Each matrix of `LIST1` is size `(p,q)` and `LIST2` contains column matrices of size `(p,1)`. I want to combine each of LIST2 column matrices to each LIST1. I tried `lapply`, but couldn't figure that out. The size of the output list is `mn`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a nested loop with `lapply`:

```
unlist(lapply(LIST1, function(x) lapply(LIST2, cbind, x)), recursive = F)
```

---

Here is a small reproducible example:

```
LIST1 <- list(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2), matrix(2:5, nrow = 2))
LIST2 <- list(matrix(1:2, nrow = 2))
unlist(lapply(LIST1, function(x) lapply(LIST2, cbind, x)), recursive = F)

#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    3
#[2,]    2    2    4

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    4
#[2,]    2    3    5
```

Comment: `Map(cbind, LIST2, LIST1)` ? I'm not sure if I'm misinterpreting the question though?

Comment: @thelatemail I think OP wants all the combinations from the two lists. With size of m * n.